# Communicating with other apps and getting data from them

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, youtube-api, app-store

On the click of a button in my app I want to launch the youtube app and check if a user is signed in and retrieve his youtube channel address and save it somewhere in my app. At first I though I could have the button open safari and take the user to the youtube sign in page and once he signs in ill copy the url of his homepage, but I dont think this possible and if it is there will be a lot of problems that I have to take into account.

Anyone got any ideas on how this could be done?

Answer (score 2):

Since iOS uses app sandboxing you can't retrieve information from other apps, unless they explicitly call your app back.

You may use [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/ios?ver=swift) to achieve what you want. The user would log in Youtube within your app, then you get the user's channel info.

Comment: can i do that for facebook, instagram and twitter too?

Comment: I think so, just search for their APIs and check out which methods they provide

Comment: I was able to complete everything but I am struggling with youtube's api how can I get the channel id? I want the user to be able link his youtube channel that he is currently logged in to. From there I want to retrieve his channel id .. Do you have any idea how this can be implemented ?